# Function returning table and IN operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres and have following schema:

```
create table a(a int);
create table b(b int);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f() RETURNS table(a int)
LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
  select a from a
$$;
```

Now I want to run following query:

```
select * from b where b in f();
```

Unfortunately it returns syntax error, but following query works fine:

```
select * from b where b in (select * from f());
```

Is there any way to achieve first type of query, since second is more verbose? Maybe I can return not Table but some other type for that?

Thank you.

Comment: does it work if you just put brackets arround your function without select?
in ( f() )

Comment: SQL isn't a language designed around brevity. The second query works fine.

Comment: I don't think you can but I think will be better to consider using a JOIN instead of IN with subquery and also consider creating indexes.

Comment: Extra brackets don't fix the query..

Comment: You wouldn't expect `where b in some_table_name` to work. Would you? A function returning a set/table is **exactly** the same thing. You have to use it like a table.

Comment: In also works on set/arrays, e.g. IN (1,2,3)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN

> expression IN (subquery)

so `select * from b where b in f();` looks like `... where b in a`, and thus it is not subquery. neither it is a values list. and so it does not work... meanwhile `select * from b where b in (select * from f())` works and should work, because it is a proper subquery.

the way to achieve the above without subquery is join (but you have to mind, that join returns duplicate results, if a.a contains duplicate values):

```
select DISTINCT b.* 
from b 
join f() on b.b = f.a
```

**updated** regarding Oto Shavadze precious remark

Comment: Yes,  only note that `join`  returns duplicate results, if  `a.a` contains duplicate values.